# Variable inside laravel query builder is always null

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

Im trying to find the users that has commented the product this way:

```
public function getUserToRate(Product $product)
{
    $userIds = DB::table('product_ratings')->where('product_id', $product->id)->pluck('user_id');

    return $userIds;
}
```

But the thing is that $product->id is null. This is what comes out if I do:

```
DB::table('product_ratings')->where('product_id', $product->id)->toSql():
```

```
select * from `product_ratings` where `product_id` = ?
```

Why is my `$product->id` null? I have checked and the model exists, but I cant seem to use it inside the query builder.

Can anyone lend me a hand? Thanks

Comment: how does that make you think it is `null`?

Comment: Because in the query it is marked as ' ? ' so I'm assuming its a null value, isnt it?

Comment: no, it means it is a parameter for a prepared statement, the SQL statement and its parameter are sent separately to the database .... look into "prepared statements"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a product model. So ignore Route Model binding like Product $product. Instead you can use your $oroductId. And query the UserIds like this:

```
public function getUserToRate( $productId)
{
    $userIds = ProductRating::where('product_id', $productId)->pluck('user_id');

    return $userIds;
}
```

Comment: I've tried like this but it's not working anyways, the query still looks like this: select * from `product_ratings` where `product_id` = ?

Comment: can I see your route that hit this function.and also the code you call that route